# why php json_decode only accept integer, not strings?

Tags: php, json

Being hitting my had for a few days and finally came to realize that my json syntax is not being accept by php json_decode. It seems to work only when the value is a integer, not a string. How can I manage to use a json such as the following to work?

```
<?php
$json = '{"fname":2,"surname":2}'; //return No errors
// $json = '{"fname": SJ011MS,"surn": something}'; //return Syntax error, malformed JSON

$obj = json_decode($json, true);
switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo ' - No errors';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
        break;
        default:
            echo ' - Unknown error';
        break;
    }
?>
```

essentially I'm planning to use a json such as:

```
{"widget": {
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is; your final json is fine and your malformed json misses quotes. But you already seem to know that.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely malformed JSON:

```
$json = '{"fname": SJ011MS,"surn": something}'
```

You have to enclose the strings using `"` (not even single quotes `'`). It should really be:

```
$json = '{"fname": "SJ011MS","surn": "something"}'
//-----------------^-------^---------^---------^
```

JSON can have only the primitive JavaScript types, arrays and objects.

[image]
<sub>(source: [json.org](https://www.json.org/value.gif))</sub>

Comment: Should this be closed as a Typo?

Comment: thanks for the help guys, I'm getting my head around to understand this

Comment: @Diego You got the answer or not?

Comment: yes, my mistake was not using " on strings, ruckie mistake, thanks again

Comment: @Diego Consider accepting answer by clicking on the tick button next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't valid JSON:

```
{"fname": SJ011MS,"surn": something}
```

The property values need to be in quotes as well:

```
{"fname": "SJ011MS","surn": "something"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your example json

```
{"widget": {
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}
```

I have written following **code**, which seems to work perfectly:-

```
<?php
$json = '{"widget": {
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}';
$decodedJson = json_decode($json,TRUE);
echo $json;
print_r($decodedJson);
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{"widget": {
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}Array
(
    [widget] => Array
        (
            [text] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Click Here
                    [size] => 36
                    [style] => bold
                    [name] => text1
                    [hOffset] => 250
                    [vOffset] => 100
                    [alignment] => center
                    [onMouseUp] => sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;
                )

        )

)
```

The **Thing to Learn** here is that if JSON property contains any string then it should be within **"quotes"**.